# Offset FormulaR1C1 each Button Click

Tags: excel, vba

I want to move my formula references from the function inside B15 two columns to the right each time the code is run.  (I want make a macro button out of it)

```
'This is the initial reference position: 
Range("B15").FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[-11]C[1]+R[-11]C[3])/(R[-14]C[3]+R[-14]C[1])"

'Next reference position would be this:
Range("B15").FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[-11]C[3]+R[-11]C[5])/(R[-14]C[5]+R[-14]C[3])"
```

I tried putting in variables for the c values but had trouble looping it forward more than once.

Any ideas on how to structure the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since it is a string you can loop through each character and check for the C[ knowing the next digits until ] are numeric (if you don't want to use global vars).  Extract them and add 2.  Here is an example of how to do that

```
Sub button1_click()
Dim sFormula As String
Dim sParts As String
Dim cChar As String
Dim cFound As Boolean
Dim bracketFound As Boolean
Dim i As Long
cFound = False
bracketFound = False


sParts = Range("B15").FormulaR1C1
'loop through the string
For i = 1 To Len(sParts)
    If cFound = True Then 'did we already find the C in the string
        If bracketFound = True Then 'did we already find the first bracket
            Dim iCount As Long
            iCount = 0 'how many numeric digits we will have
            While IsNumeric(Mid(sParts, i + iCount + 1, 1)) = True 'check each digit after to see if it is numeric
                iCount = iCount + 1
            Wend

            cChar = CStr(CInt(Mid(sParts, i, 1 + iCount)) + 2) 'get our number and add 2
            'update i
            i = i + iCount
            'reset flags
            bracketFound = False
            cFound = False
        Else
            If Mid(sParts, i, 1) = "[" Then 'check for inner bracket
                bracketFound = True
                cChar = Mid(sParts, i, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Else
        If Mid(sParts, i, 1) = "C" Then 'check for the C char
            cFound = True
            cChar = Mid(sParts, i, 1)
        Else
            cChar = Mid(sParts, i, 1)
        End If
    End If
    sFormula = sFormula & cChar 'update formula

Next i
'set the new formula
Range("B15").FormulaR1C1 = sFormula

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm very impressed!  Not only did you take the time to write perfectly running code but you also helped comment it out to help me learn to one day be as awesome as you!  Thank you.